# Current Source that produces transverse electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Given only $y$ component of Electromagnetic Field $\vec{E}$,

$$E_y = \begin{cases} E_0\cos(\omega z/c - \omega t), & \mbox{ z > 0} \\ E_0\cos(\omega z/c + \omega t), & \mbox{z < 0} \end{cases}$$

I am asked to find the current source that produces this field.

So I worked on

\begin{array}{lcl} \vec{E} & = &  -\vec{\nabla}\phi -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \\ \vec{B} & = & \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}  \end{array}

But I couldn't related them to produce meaning results.

First things first,

1. How come this field becomes an electromagnetic field? Why don't I see "magnetic field" for both cases?
2. Should I jump from Coulomb gauge to Lorentz gauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We know that this field is an electromagnetic field because it is a function of space and time. From Amperes law we know that the time rate of change of electric field (derivative with respect to time) generates a magnetic field, from Faraday's law we know that the time rate of change (derivative with respect to time) of magnetic field generates electric field. So every field generates the other, that is why it is an electromagnetic field.
2. You don't need to bother with gauge, having the electric field you can obtain the expression of the magnetic field (B) for z > 0 and z < 0. At point z = 0 (where the current is situated) You will find they have the same expression, the only difference is a minus sign. Having the same magnetic field with different signs to left and right is known to be the magnetic field generated by infinite current sheet. The relation between magnetic field and the current flowing on the sheet is give by the equation in yellow [here](http://www.physics.byu.edu/faculty/christensen/Physics%20220/FTI/30%20Sources%20of%20the%20Magnetic%20Field/30.14%20Magnetic%20field%20of%20an%20infinite%20current%20sheet.htm)

Hope that helped